# JOOQ query to get the latest record of each user

Tags: java, database, postgresql, record, jooq

I have created a dirty way of doing this which works but wondering if there's a simpler way I can obtain this. Basically I just want to get the latest user tool id's finished for each user. Thanks in advance!

```
var allUserTools = masterDB.select(Tool.USER_ID, Tool.USER_TOOL_ID)
                    .from(Tool.TABLE)
                    .orderBy(Tool.FINISHED.desc())
                    .fetchGroups(Tool.USER_ID, UserTool.USER_TOOL_ID));


    List<Integer> allUserToolIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> userTool : allUserTools.entrySet()) {
        if(!userTool.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            allUserToolIDs.add(userTool.getValue().get(0));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a [TOP N per category query](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/), and more specifically, since you're only interested in the "TOP 1" row per category (or group), there's a simple solution for PostgreSQL, using [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-distinct-on/):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (USER_ID), USER_ID, USER_TOOL_ID
FROM TOOL
ORDER BY USER_ID, FINISHED DESC
```

This can be read as getting only distinct values for the `(USER_ID, USER_TOOL_ID)` tuple, preferring the first one according to the `ORDER BY` clause. It's a rather esoteric syntax for something that could also be done with window functions, more verbosely (see the manual page).

In jOOQ:

```java
masterDB.select(TOOL.USER_ID, TOOL.USER_TOOL_ID)
        .distinctOn(TOOL.USER_ID)
        .from(TOOL)
        .orderBy(TOOL.USER_ID, TOOL.USER_TOOL_ID, TOOL.FINISHED.desc())
        .fetch();
```

Comment: The only issue i'm still having is that it's not getting the latest FINISHED result

Comment: Removing TOOL.USER_TOOL_ID from the order by was the fix

Comment: @JacksonCollins: Right, my bad

Comment: That's fine, thank you for the help